# What is the Bonjour service _acp-sync._tcp used for? And why is it accessing my Apple AirPort Base station using a long and obscure string?

Tags: airport, bonjour, tcp

Scanning for Bonjour devices on my network shows a long and obscure string associated with my AirPort Base station using this Bonjour protocol _acp-sync._tcp. What is this? What is it for?

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour advertises the services on devices

example

```
HOSTNAME._smb._tcp
```

Means the device is sharing folders via smb over TCP (as opposed to using UDP). It is also used with things like AirPrint to share printers.

Now

```
_acp-sync._tcp
```

Its over tcp.
It would seem ACP is some sort of configuration protocol used by the monitoring and configuration utilities for the AirPort.

Some people have tried to reverse engineer

https://github.com/x56/airpyrt-tools

I think natutil will tell you that its using TCP Port 5009

> Apple AirPort Admin Utility, AirPort Express Assistant, Xwis (TCP/UDP) - Source SG
> airport-admin Apple AirPort WAP Administration (TCP) - Source NMAP

So yes its some sort of configuration protocol

Answer (score 0):

It is done so that the Airport base station, in its role as a NAT internet gateway, can advertise status information to devices on the local network. Status information includes things as whether or not an internet connection is available, the status of the LAN port on the base station, and possible information about active port mappings.

It used to be that you could use the command `natutil` on macOS to show that information in a human-readable form. However, I don't think it is included in Catalina and Big Sur.